# Extracting tables containing a string with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html-parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a website which contains many tables within tables within tables etc, using BeautifulSoup. Specifically I am looking at [websites of this form](http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=5634&advv=Y). I could like to extract the relevant tables, e.g. those of match statistics, but can't seem to find a way to extract the relevant tables, as they don't contain distinguishing features such as a particular class etc.

Is there a way to extract tables which contain certain strings?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just doing something like:

```
soup.findAll("table", {"width": "585"})
```

It seems to me that all of the statistic based tables are of set width 585px.  While this may change, it seems like a good place to start.

As far as I know there is not a way to do a search for an element containing a string.  However, there is nothing to stop you from using `findAll('table')` then iterating each table looking for your string.  When you find it, process the table.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! I actually tried something similar but ran into trouble.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract tables that contain a string, for example:

```
for tag in soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Sydney Match Statistics')):
        print tag.findParent('table').findParent('table')
```

This finds the element that contains the text "Sydney Match Statistics" and then it finds the `table` containing it, and then another `table` containing that.

The `.parent` and `.next_sibling` methods seem also useful for your case to navigate to the right elements after finding the one containing a relevant string.